# Automapper Finding Not Mapped properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, automapper

Using Automapper for a project, just mapping 2 objects to each other, nothing fancy. I must have something configured incorrectly because AutoMapper keeps saying that there are UnMapped Properties.
Here's the AutoMapper config.

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {cfg.CreateMap<SrcObj, DestObj>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Level, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.lvl));}
mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

SrcObj

```
public  class SrcObj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentNode { get; set; }

    public string Controller { get; set; }

    public string Action { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    public string AreaName { get; set; }

    public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    public Int64 Type{ get; set; }

    public int lvl { get; set; }
}
```

DestObj

```
public  class DestObj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentNode { get; set; }

    public string Controller { get; set; }

    public string Action { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    public string AreaName { get; set; }

    public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    public Int64 Type{ get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

And the Implementation:

```
var items  = await _context.Database.SqlQuery<SrcObj>($"EXEC spGenerateMenu {app1}").ToListAsync();
var rslt = _mapper.Map<DestObj>(items);
```

and the error:

> {"\nUnmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.\nAdd a custom mapping expressio...}

The error actually lists every member of the DestObj.  Not sure what I'm missing.  probably something simple

Comment: Test your configuration if it is [valid](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html) and see what comes up.

Comment: I'm using validation and it passes... I added it in to the example above.

Comment: this line `mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` asserts that every property is mapped. 9 out of 10 times it'll get in your way. Just remove it, or explicitly map every single property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your source is a `List`, you need to map it also to a `List`:

```
var rslt = _mapper.Map<List<DestObj>>(items);
```

Comment: Usually things are more clear if you set CreateMissingTypeMaps to false.